# Passing multiple files through stdin (over ssh)

Tags: ssh, io-redirection

I have a program on a remote host, whose execution I need to automate. The command execute that program, on the same machine, looks something like this:

```
/path/to/program -a file1.txt -b file2.txt
```

In this case, `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` are used for entirely different things within the program, so I can't just `cat` them together. However, in my case, the `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` that I want to pass into the program exist only on my device, not on the host where I need to execute the program. I know that I can feed at least one file through SSH by passing it through `stdin`:

```
cat file1.txt | ssh host.name /path/to/program -a /dev/stdin -b file2.txt
```

but, since I'm not allowed to store files on the host, I need a way to get the `file2.txt` over there as well. I'm thinking it might be possible through abuse of environment variables and creative use of `cat` and `sed` together, but I don't know the tools well enough to understand how I would use them to accomplish this. Is it doable, and how?

Comment: `cat`and `sed` are not the solution here.

Comment: Probably I'd be able to mount, but given proxies and security constraints I'm not sure I'd be able to get away with it.

Comment: Do you have the permission in the remote machine to mount an ssh folder?

Comment: if you can open an ssh session from the remote machine to your local one, so there's no issue at the network level to mount an SSH folder.

Comment: Can you do forwardings? What systems and shells do you have at the local and the remote end?

Comment: Can't you even write files to `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` or `/dev/shm`?

Answer (score 20):

If the files given as arguments to your program are text files, and you're able to control their content (you know a line which doesn't occur inside them), you can use multiple here-documents:

```
{
    echo "cat /dev/fd/3 3<<'EOT' /dev/fd/4 4<<'EOT' /dev/fd/5 5<<'EOT'"
    cat file1
    echo EOT
    cat file2
    echo EOT
    cat file3
    echo EOT
} | ssh user@host sh
```

Here `cat` is a sample command which takes filenames as arguments. It could be instead:

```
echo "/path/to/prog -a /dev/fd/3 3<<'EOT' -b /dev/fd/4 4<<'EOT'
```

Replace each `EOT` with something that doesn't occur in each of the files, respectively.

Comment: This approach is quite clever! If the files are not text, you could encode/decode them with something like base64 or even good ol' uuencode... Very nice!

Comment: Note that several (most) sh implementations implement here documents using temporary files, so it may not work for the OP if they are not allowed to store files on the remote host.

Comment: `dash` (the `/bin/sh` in debian, ubuntu, etc), `busybox sh`, the `/bin/sh` from FreeBSD and `yash` do not use temporary files for here-documents. I've actually tested it with a read-only chroot. Of course, the `/dev/fd/` files have to be available -- on a stock FreeBSD system only `/dev/fd/0-2` are, so `fdescfs` has to be mounted on `/dev/fd`.

Comment: I'm a fan of the [ASCII information separators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text), which are designed to delimit fields without obstruction. `U+001C` is "Information Separator Four" (file separator, FS) and is ideal for this case, though binary files may make use of it coincidentally. Therefore, I'd suggest `EOT="$(printf $'\x1c')"` in advanced shells or else `EOT="$(awk 'BEGIN{printf"%c",28}')"` for compatibility. You'll need to quote it when you put it in place, such as `echo "$EOT$EOT$EOT"` (tripled to lower the odds of matching a binary file).

Comment: If you're going to use the tty why not use the *`tty`* command ? Unless I’m missing something - which I suppose is possible?

Comment: @Pryftan You're certainly missing something ;-) -- that's not using the tty. I've tried that with a chroot with no `/dev` (and no `/dev/tty`, `/dev/pts/*`, etc). And what will the `tty` command do other than printing the name of the tty connected to its stdin?

Comment: @mosvy To be fair I’m sleeping like hell and I was half asleep at the time so even if I had read it proper I probably still would have missed it. But looking back I see that (1) the options -a and -b that you used are in the OP. (2) It's taking files; you're of course right that *`tty`* only prints the tty. Where I was going is that (in my head) you were using the ttys and so why not use the command? Basically I was getting at substitution. But then the fact you use multiple ttys makes it even more ridiculous. So you're incorrect here; I was missing a lot of things and totally off! :)

Answer (score 14):

Perhaps not exactly what you want... But maybe consider sending a tarball through the pipe opened by ssh?

You said that:

> I'm not allowed to store files on the host.

It's possible that you don't have a writable home directory or other convenient location to store files long term, but I'd say it's unlikely you don't have any writable location, even if a temporary `tmpfs` that will be made available only for your particular connection.

Many programs (and even libc routines) require a writable `/tmp`, so it's very likely one will be available to you.

Then you could use a script that will unpack the tarball into a temporary directory, run your program and cleanup through the ssh connection.

Something like:

```
$ tar cf - file1.txt file2.txt |
  ssh host.name '
      set -e
      tmpdir=$(mktemp -d -t tmp.XXXXXXXXXX)
      cleanup () { rm -rf "$tmpdir"; }
      trap cleanup EXIT
      cd "$tmpdir"
      tar xf -
      /path/to/program -a file1.txt -b file2.txt
  '
```

This might need some extra care with file paths and there are some corner cases to consider (test for them), but the general approach should work.

If no writable directory is available, a possible approach would be to modify `program` to take a tarball as single input and unpack its contents to memory. For instance, if `program` is a Python script, then using the built-in `tarfile` module would easily accomplish something like that.

Comment: Even without going through the trouble of tarballing it - I've decided more or less to just write a file to `/tmp/` and use it directly.

Comment: The tarball approach has some advantages, as you use a single ssh connection (no need to test for success/failure) and multiple concurrent runs are not likely to run into each other (use and/or delete files in /tmp meant for separate runs.) But I think that's the best you'll get from ssh as it exists now. Good luck!

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy So after all, you *can* store files on the server just fine. Please modify the question accordingly.

Comment: @mosvy *can*, yes, but *don't want to*. The question stands, in a "is it possible to do this without storing any files", the answer to which appears to be "maybe, but not in my case"

Answer (score 5):

If you can set a TCP listener (can be a higher port), then you could use a second SSH session to establish the second input source with `nc`.

**Example:**

There's this script on the server (`~/script.bash`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat "$1" | tr a 1
nc localhost "$2" | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```

And there are these two files locally:

```
$ cat a 
aaa
aaa
aaa
$ cat b
bbb
bbb
bbb
```

Now first start the second source (`$serv` is the server):

```
ssh "$serv" nc -l -p 2222 -q1 <b &
```

And run the command proper:

```
$ ssh "$serv" ./script.bash - 2222 <a
111
111
111
BBB
BBB
BBB
[1]+  Done                    ssh "$serv" nc -l -p 2222 -q1 < b
```

Answer (score 2):

It was established in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/522637/87770#comment966408_522718) that `/tmp` is writable, so simply copy over one of the files beforehand:

```bsh
scp -p file2.txt host.name:/tmp/
ssh host.name "/path/to/program -a /dev/stdin -b /tmp/file2.txt && rm /tmp/file2.txt" < file1.txt
```

This also cleans up the copied file after a successful run (change the `&&` to a `;` if you want to remove it regardless of success, but then note that you'll lose the exit value).

---

If that's not acceptable, I'd propose tinkering with `/path/to/program` or a wrapper for it that can separate the two files from a single input stream such as:

```bsh
awk 'FNR == 1 && NR > 1 { printf "%c%c%c", 28, 28, 28 } 1' file1.txt file2.txt \
  | ssh host.name /path/to/tweaked_program
```

This uses [ASCII information separator four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter#ASCII_delimited_text) (file separator, FS) and has it tripled so that we minimize the chance of a binary file coincidentally containing that string. Your `tweaked_program` would then split the input given the separator and then operate on the two saved files as variables.

Of course, if you using a language that has libraries to deal with tarballs, a safer and cleaner approach would simply be to pipe `tar` into such code across `ssh` like this:

```bsh
tar -zpc file1.txt file2.txt |ssh host.name /path/to/tweaked_program
```

And your `tweaked_program` would decompress and open the archive, save each file to a different variable, and then run the original `program`'s logic on the variables.

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to forward ports over `ssh`, and you have access to `wget` on the remote machine and to `busybox` on the local machine, you can do something like:

```
mkdir /tmp/test; cd /tmp/test
echo 1st_file > 1st_file
echo 2nd_file > 2nd_file

busybox httpd -f -p 127.0.0.1:11080 &
ssh USER@HOST -R 10080:127.0.0.1:11080 '
        cat <(wget -q -O- http://localhost:10080/1st_file) \
            <(wget -q -O- http://localhost:10080/2nd_file)
'
kill $!
```

(using `cat` as an example program which takes two file arguments).

Only the ability to forward ports via `-R` is essential -- instead of doing http, you can use other methods, eg. if your  `netcat` supports the `-d` and `-N` options:

```
nc -Nl localhost 11001 < 1st_file &
nc -Nl localhost 11002 < 2nd_file &
ssh USER@HOST -R 10001:localhost:11001 -R 10002:localhost:11002 '
        cat <(nc -d localhost 10001) <(nc -d localhost 10002)
```

There may be ways to replace the `<(...)` process substitutions if the login shell on the remote machine isn't ksh- or bash- like.

All in all, this isn't too great -- better knowledge about the exact system/shells/config/permissions (which you haven't provided) could allow for smarter solutions.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:** This doesn't really work, ssh has a very set idea of what stdin and stdout/stderr mean and doesn't really allow usurping stderr to read from it. I will delete this answer in a few days since it doesn't work. Thanks for the very interesting discussion!!!

---

Unfortunately there's not a great way to do this directly, since the `ssh` client will only pass the three file descriptors (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) to the server and it doesn't have provisions to pass additional file descriptors (which would be helpful for this particular use case.)

(Also note that the SSH protocol has provisions to pass additional file descriptors, only the `ssh` client doesn't implement a way to use that feature. Theoretically, extending the client with a patch would be enough to expose this feature.)

One *hacky* way to accomplish what you're looking for is to use file descriptor 2 (the `stderr` file descriptor) to pass the second file. Something like:

```
$ ssh remote.name \
      /path/to/program -a /dev/stdin -b /dev/stderr \
      <file1.txt 2<file2.txt
```

This should work, it just might cause an issue if `program` tries to write to stderr. You can work around that by re-juggling the file descriptors on the remote end before you run program. You can move `file2.txt` to file descriptor 3 and re-open stderr to mirror stdout:

```
$ ssh remote.name \
      /path/to/program -a /dev/stdin -b /dev/fd/3 \
      '3<&2' '2>&1' \
      <file1.txt 2<file2.txt
```

Comment: I haven't really tested this (typing on a phone) but at least in theory I'd expect it to work. Let me know if for some reason it doesn't. Cheers!

Comment: That won't work at all. Not even with a hacked ssh. AFAIK stderr doesn't use a separate channel, but some special kind of message. But yes, being able to access ssh channels as pipes or unnamed unix domain sockets (instead of having to do socket forwardings) would be great, it just doesn't seem to be possible in any kind or shape.

Comment: @mosvy, fd 0, 1 and 2 on the remote command will be 3 different pipes. The data travels through 3 different channels multiplexed in the ssh connection, but those are uni-directional (from client to sever for fd 0 and from server to client for 1 and 2),  so even on systems where pipes are bidirectional, that won't work. On Linux, openening /dev/stderr in readonly mode gives on the other end of the pipe, so it would never work either.

Comment: Note that the last one assumes the login shell of the user on remote.name is Bourne-like (`3<&2` is a Bourne shell operator, and sshd runs the login shell of the user to interpret the command sent by the client)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I'm not sure that stdin/out/err travels through 3 separate channels. My impression was that they use a single (bi-directional as all) channel, and the stderr use some special tagged message. I will check.

Comment: @mosvy, that tagging would then be how the different _channels_ are implemented in the ssh protocol. In any case, the data (for those 3 fds, for port forwards, socks forward, X11 tunnelling...) travels through a singe TCP connection, ssh multiplexes those with encryption.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nope, a single ssh channel is used for stdin/stdout/stderr, and the stderr data is transferred via `SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA` messages with the type set to `SSH_EXTENDED_DATA_STDERR`. You can read the whole thing [here](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4254#section-5.2)

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, sorry. Trying the initial suggestion led to the program hanging, and trying the latter just ended up doing nothing. And that aside, I actually need the untainted stdout output, so sending stderr to it might not be what I want (would sending stderr to `/dev/null` also hypothetically re-open it?)

Comment: Or, actually, upon further experimentation, the latter suggestion yielded the same result as the former suggestion - the program hung on the other end.

Comment: @mosvy, my point was that regardless of how the data ends up being tagged in the ssh protocol, stdout and stderr are not merged in a single stream (here using "stream" instead of "channel" to avoid confusion with internal ssh terminology which I take it is the point your objecting to), they are still sent on two different streams which the client can separate, but the point is that those streams are unidirectional, the client is not reading from its stderr.